# Trying to count Characters from user input but it is also counting [""] not just the users input word.

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, count

I am trying to count and display the character count from a users input word. I kind of figured out how to change the word from a string to a character but it shows the [""] in the count along with the letters. I need it to just count and display the letters. Example: user inputs Test,
Letter : Count
e    :    1,
s     :   1,
t    :    2
(Can't get it to show like it should in the program)
Number of keys in charcount dictionary: 3

```
import Foundation
var myWord: [String] = [] //Array for word given by user
//var count = 0 //create a variable to hold the count for any matches


//get input from user - must use Objective C code since Swift 1+ doesn't have an input function (code used from Dawn Wick StudentTests code)
func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    let strData = NSString(data: inputData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    return strData.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
}

print("Enter a word: ", terminator: "")

var userWord = input()     // get users word
myWord.append(userWord) //Append myWord array with user input

//Summarize character counts
var charCount: [Character : Int] = [:]

//Summarize occurences of each character
for char in myWord.description.characters{
    //if char in Dictionary, increment count, otherwise add it
    if let count = charCount[char] {
        charCount[char] = count + 1 //increment count
    }else {
        charCount[char] = 1 //add char to dictionary
    }
}


print("THE WORD \(myWord) CONTAINS:", terminator: " ");
print("\nLETTERS\t\t COUNT\n", terminator: " ");
for (char, count) in charCount {
    print("\n \(char) \t \(count)", terminator: " ");
}
print("\nNumber OF KEYS IN CHARCOUNTS DICTIONARY: \(charCount.count)", terminator: " ");
```

I would be very grateful for any help. 
Thank you.

Comment: one approach is to use regex to extract all letters before you do your counting. Another approach is to use map to hardcode the 52 letters and check if the char exist in this map before adding the count.

Comment: I am new to swift and learning the basics in this class. I have no clue about the options you are talking about. I wish I did though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `myWord.description.characters`, you're getting the `[`, `]` and `"`.

You should be using:

```
myWord.forEach {
    $0.characters.forEach {
        charCount[$0] = (charCount[$0] ?? 0) + 1
    }
}
```

Since you're counting all the `Characters` and put them in dictionary, you could simplify it a bit:

```
myWord.flatMap { $0.characters }.forEach {
    charCount[$0] = (charCount[$0] ?? 0) + 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That made it work just like it needed to. Glad this site is here cause the book doesn't cover anything like this at all.

Comment: You're right, SO is indeed very useful! I've updated the answer a bit, adding a simplified version :).